# Segmentation fault: 11, when I test heapsort code from book 'Introduction to Algorithms'

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I performed pseudo-code of heapsort in book 'Introduction of Algorithms' with C, and an error occurred: Segmentation fault: 11. Is there any problem with memory overflow?

```
#define LEFT(i) 2*i;
#define RIGHT(i) 2*i+1;
#define PARENT(i) i/2;

/************************************************/
/*heap_sort -- stable
*In order to easily determine the relationship of index between parent node and child nodes,
*available index of arr starts from 1.
*/
/************************************************/

/*
    Available index of arr starts from 1.
    Length represents the last element's index.
    Heap_size is biggest range in arr.
*/
typedef struct {
    int heap_size;
    int length;
    int *arr;
} heap;

/*
    Node i's left_child tree and right_child tree are all max heap.
    This function put node i's value into proper position in oder to keep a max heap.
*/
void max_heapify(heap h, int i) {
    int *arr = h.arr;
    int left = LEFT(i);
    int right = RIGHT(i);
    int largest = i;

    if (arr[left] > arr[i] && left <= h.heap_size)
        largest = left;
    if (arr[right] > arr[largest] && right <= h.heap_size)
        largest = right;

    if (largest != i) {
        exchange(h.arr + i, h.arr + largest);
        max_heapify(h, largest);
    }

    return;
}

/*
    Build a max heap.
*/
void build_max_heap(heap h) {
    h.heap_size = h.length;
    for (int i = h.length / 2; i > 0; i--)  //leaf nodes need not to call max_heapify
        max_heapify(h, i);
    return;
}

void heap_sort(heap h) {
    build_max_heap(h);
    int *arr = h.arr;
    for (int i = h.length; i > 1; i--) {
        exchange(arr + 1, arr + i);
        h.heap_size--;
        max_heapify(h, 1);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,4,9,0,2,1,6,2};
    int num = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    heap h = {0, num - 1, arr};
    heap_sort(h);
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d,", arr[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Max heap is a binary tree in which a node's value is bigger than both its left and right child nodes' value.

Comment: @2501Here is the information. bootstrap.sh: line 10: 23179 Segmentation fault: 11  "$A_OUT"

Comment: where is the definition of LEFT, RIGHT etc?

Comment: `max_heapify` : It requires an end condition of recursive call.

Comment: #define LEFT(i) 2*i;
#define RIGHT(i) 2*i+1;
#define PARENT(i) i/2; LEFT means its left child node.@samgak

Comment: You are right, I should put 'max_heapify(h, largest);' into the {} above. Thanks.@BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `max_heapify()` function, first you need to check if `left` or `right` is still in bounds - i.e. they are `<= h.heap_size`, and only if they are in bound, then you need to evaluate values of `arr[left]`, or `arr[right]`. But, you are doing the other way round. So, your program crashes when it tries to access `arr[left]` or `arr[right]` when try are out-of-bound. This can be fixed by changing the order of conditions in your `if` statement as seen below.

```
void max_heapify(heap h, int i) {
    int *arr = h.arr;
    int left = LEFT(i);
    int right = RIGHT(i);
    int largest = i;

    /* ISSUE: You are evaluating first, checking bounds second */   
    /* if (arr[left] > arr[i] && left <= h.heap_size) */ 

    /* Right way: Check bounds first, evaluate second */
    if (left <= h.heap_size && arr[left] > arr[i]) /* Right */
        largest = left;

    /* ISSUE: You are evaluating first, checking bounds second */ 
    /* if (arr[right] > arr[largest] && right <= h.heap_size) */

    /* Right way: Check bounds first, evaluate second */
    if (right <= h.heap_size && arr[right] > arr[largest])
        largest = right;

    if (largest != i) {
        exchange(h.arr + i, h.arr + largest);
        max_heapify(h, largest);
    }

    return;
}
```

---

Above change should resolve your program crash.

But there is one more issue in your code - not related to your program crash, but gives you wrong result. You need to set `h.heap_size = h.length` in your `heap_sort()` function too. This is because, since you are passing your heap, `h`, by value, setting `h.heap_size = h.length;` in `build_max_heap()` function will not affect the value of `h.heap_size` in `heap_sort()` function. You need to do that in `heap_sort()` function explicitly again.

```
void heap_sort(heap h)
{
    build_max_heap(h);
    int *arr = h.arr;
    h.heap_size = h.length; /* This statement REQUIRED here */
    for (int i = h.length; i > 1;  i--)
    {
            exchange(arr + 1, arr + i); 
            h.heap_size = h.heap_size - 1;
            max_heapify(h, 1); 
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, you perfectly solved my problem.